# nib control action never fired

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I have a view that slides in from the bottom ("slideover"), and covers a part of the screen (about a third). Like a popover, but appears from the bottom.

The content of the slideover is defined in an own nib, `ConfirmView.xib`. The nib has a controller connected, `ConfirmViewController.swift`. The controllers makes the view appear animated.

I've tried to connect control actions to the controller, but however the action function is never fired. I've tried to add outlets to my controls in the view, and changing values of the controls which works fine.

I've tried both to use a `UISlider` and a `UIButton`, with the `Value changed` and `Touch up inside` events of the Files owner triggering the functions, but nothing works. The controls respond to user interaction, so the layout shouldn't be the issue.

I open the `ConfirmView` like this

```
let popViewController : ConfirmViewController = ConfirmViewController(nibName: "ConfirmView", bundle: nil)
popViewController.showInView(self.parentViewController?.view, animated: true, frame: (self.parentViewController?.view.frame)!)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you copy pasted these buttons from some other nib, and they have wrong actions with them? Delete all connections and re connect and try

Comment: No I haven't, all connections are made by me myself.

Comment: Just found out that all my outlets become `nil` after `viewDidLoad` has executed (or might be some other internal function, but the outlets are not `nil` when `viewDidLoad` is executing)

Comment: @AntonGildebrand what is inside the `showInView` method?

Comment: Only this row `aView.addSubView(self.view)` where aView is the first argument of `showInView`